# How to Use the loginid value in Entire application in wpf

Tags: wpf

I have an application where the userid should be available in all the forms in Wpf. I have written the code like this

In form1 I wrote like this

```
 var login =
                    context.Logins.FirstOrDefault(
                        x => x.EmailAddress == email && x.Password == password);
                if (login != null)
                {
                    fp.Show();
                    Application.Current.Properties["UserId"] = login.Id; 
                    Close();
                }
```

In the form2 I should be accessible to the userid so I wrote the code like this

```
 var  userid = (int) Application.Current.Properties["UserId"];
        int id = userid;
```

I am getting system null reference exception :{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

any help

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in a simple configuration, something else is going on in your code that I am not sure of. This my test code, see if you can break it. I used a timer just to verify that closing your main form didn't kill the setting.  I am not sure wether or not your form fp is the form you are calling form2, but if it is you need to save your setting before you you Show it, instead of after as you are doing now.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.Current.Properties["UserId"] = 12;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 win1 = new Window1();
        win1.Show();
        Close();
    }
}
```

**Window1**

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer tmr = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tmr.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
        tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);
        tmr.Start();
    }

    void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tmr.Stop();
        var userid = (int)Application.Current.Properties["UserId"];
        int id = userid;
        this.Title = Application.Current.Properties["UserId"].ToString();
    }


}
```